# Кто и зачем мог отправлять данный пакет по TCP/IP?

Tags: безопасность, ssh, tcp-ip

Есть написанный мною развернутый сервис (он открыт в общий доступ через доменное имя), который принимает TCP/IP соединения и обрабатывает пакеты данных определенного формата. Сегодня к данному сервису подключился странный клиент, который с интервалом в ~ 2 минуты 50 секунд слал пакеты со следующим содержимым:

```
SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.8.0
```

Мой сервис такие пакеты естественно отбрасывает и выкидывает ошибку.

Вопрос: Что это может быть? Попытка подключения к машине через SSH? И нужно ли что-то с этим делать?

---

Переходя по IP-адресу этого "странного клиента" в браузере открывается default-страница `Apache2 Debian Default Page`.

Comment: "Кто и зачем мог петь *"я тучка-тучка-тучка, я вовсе не медведь"* под моим окном?" Не найдете, не спросите - не узнаете.

Comment: кстати, чтобы найти все сайты, которые используют данный ip (может быть полезным для выхода на владельца того сервера, с которого к вам подключаются), можно воспользоваться всякими онлайновыми lookup-ерами. типа [такого](https://suip.biz/?act=hostmap) или [такого](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/), тысячи их…

Comment: Да просто китайцы хацкают небось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы всё-таки был хоть какой-то ответ, приведу маленькую симуляцию.

запустил я процесс *netcat*, слушающий порт 2222 (номер выбран произвольно) и попытался осуществить подключение к этому порту по протоколу ssh с использованием библиотеки libssh2 (это имя фигурирует в вопросе).

в *debian gnu/linux* данная библиотека идёт в пакете `libssh2-1` (версии как раз `1.8.0` — в стабильном на данный момент выпуске дистрибутива), и зависит от неё много чего (есть и php-шные биндинги, и python-овские), но у меня в системе оказался установленным только один биндинг — для программы [r](/questions/tagged/r), идущий в r-пакете `git2r` (реализация работы с git-репозиториями).

вот я и запустил как бы клонирование как бы репозитория как бы находящегося по адесу `localhost:2222` (где уже слушает мой «сервер» — программа *netcat*). здесь главное — что будет осуществляться попытка подключения именно по протоколу ssh и как раз с использованием библиотеке *libssh2*:

```
$ r -e "git2r::clone('ssh://fake@localhost:2222/fake','.')"
cloning into '.'...
```

и в то же мгновение *netcat* получил строку, идентичную полученной вашим сервером:

```
$ nc -l -p 2222
SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.8.0
```

---

для полноты изложения — цитата из [соответствующего rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2):

```
4.2.  Protocol Version Exchange

   When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an
   identification string.  This identification string MUST be

      SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
```

---

вывод: скорее всего, к вашему серверу пытается подключиться (используя протокол ssh) некая программа/скрипт, либо действительно использующая *libssh2*, либо мимикрирующая использование этой библиотеки.